# How to show only one month in ngx-daterangepicker-material date range picker?

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-daterangepicker-material

I want to show only one month in date range picker like mentioned below.

[Current Date Range Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeVCq.png)

And I want something like this.

[Single month show in Date range picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNVL4.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] first

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5468463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see the right option from the docs, so I just removed the right side of the calendar.

```js
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { DaterangepickerDirective } from 'ngx-daterangepicker-material';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(DaterangepickerDirective, { static: true })
  picker: DaterangepickerDirective;
  selected: { startDate: moment.Moment; endDate: moment.Moment };
  name = 'Angular';
  open() {
    this.picker.open();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const rightCalendar = document.getElementsByClassName('calendar right');
    if (rightCalendar.item(0)) {
      rightCalendar.item(0).remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Html

```html
<input type="text" matInput
    ngxDaterangepickerMd
    [locale]="{applyLabel: 'ok', format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'}"
    startKey="start"
    endKey="end"
    [alwaysShowCalendars]="false"
    [(ngModel)]="selected"
    name="daterange"/>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-daterangepicker-material-for-angular8-zucirm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Please do not encourage low quality posts by answering. The question post has zero code, it is off-topic on SO. Please use your voting power to vote to close this kind of questions until the OP edits to a SO's acceptable standards quality. SO is not a forum, not a chat, it is a wiki, we should expect higher quality than some images. It will anyway end up by back and forth comments and some frustrations

Comment: I agree, but you've already made your remarks on that matter and hopefully OP will refactor their question to more acceptable standards. Because he's a new user I am certainly willing to give him the benefit of doubt to rectify himself still while giving my best to provide an quality answer with given information. Even if the topic gets closed, the question is not going to disappear. And besides, I found the question intriguing and indeed it does seem like a unique problem - even if the question was of poor quality.

Comment: Thank you so much, This worked for me but how do we add filters like last month on top of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `displayMonths` option in the config.

###### Template:

```html
<bs-daterangepicker-inline
  [bsValue]="bsInlineRangeValue"
  [bsConfig]="config"
></bs-daterangepicker-inline>
```

###### Code behind:

```
config: Partial<BsDaterangepickerInlineConfig> = {
  displayMonths: 1
}
```